# How to unit test a sphinxdoc extension with coverage (in PyCharm)?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pytest

So I've written a number of sphinxdoc extensions, e.g. this one (used as an example since it is the simplest one):

```
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.statemachine import StringList
from sphinx.util.compat import Directive

class SvnRevisionDirective(Directive):
    """Directive to display subversion revision of the path.
    """
    has_content = True
    required_arguments = 1
    optional_arguments = 1
    final_argument_whitespace = False
    option_spec = {}

    def run(self):
        path = self.arguments[0]
        # rev = svntools.Revision(path)
        rev = 42
        paragraph = nodes.paragraph()
        self.state.nested_parse(
            StringList([
                '**Revision:** r%d' % rev
            ]), 0, paragraph)
        return [paragraph]

def setup(app):
    """Directive framework code.
    """
    app.add_directive('svnrevision', SvnRevisionDirective)
```

after the path to the extension is added to `extensions` in the documentation's `conf.py` it can be used like:

```
.. svnrevision:: mypackage/__init__.py
```

and will produce:

**Revision:** r42

To just test that it is working I can create a `tests/testproj` directory and fill it with a `docs` directory, a `conf.py` file, and an `index.rst` file containing the directive, and use:

```
import os
import pytest
DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_svnrevision(monkeypatch):
    testprojdir = os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'testproj')
    monkeypatch.setenv('PYTHONPATH', testprojdir, os.pathsep)
    monkeypatch.setenv('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'testingapp.settings')
    monkeypatch.chdir(DIRNAME)
    cmd = 'sphinx-build -bhtml -a -E testproj/docs testproj/build'
    os.system(cmd)
```

but this gives a lot of distance between the test and the code, and doesn't give me code coverage, at least not when ran under PyCharm.

I would like something more direct, similar to e.g.:

```
def test_svnrevision():
    rst = """
        .. svnrevision:: mypackage/__init__.py
    """
    svndirective = SvnRevisionDirective(...., rst, ...)
    result = svndirective.run()
    assert result.___ == '**Revision:** 42'
```

is this possible?

Comment: Related sphinx issue: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3458

Answer (score 2):

If you were using unittest or nose, you could try to use [sphinx-testing](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx-testing) module, which is available on PyPI.

For pytest based unit tests, [the approach differs based on Sphinx version you are using](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3458).

Since Sphinx 1.6.1, you can use pytest plugin `sphinx.testing.fixtures` as described in [Sphinx Developer’s Guide](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/devguide.html#unit-testing). While this feature is still experimental, it seems to be much better option compared to the other one described below.

For pytest tests with Sphinx <= 1.6.0, there is no way to reuse Sphinx testing fixtures directly. One can try to copy `contest.py`, `path.py` and `util.py` files from [`sphinx/tests` directory](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/tree/master/tests) into your own project and hack `util.py` file a bit to get it working without custom sphinx runner (`run.py` file):

```
+# code from run.py
+testroot = os.path.dirname(__file__) or '.'
+# find a temp dir for testing and clean it up now
+os.environ['SPHINX_TEST_TEMPDIR'] = \
+    os.path.abspath(os.path.join(testroot, 'build')) \
+    if 'SPHINX_TEST_TEMPDIR' not in os.environ \
+    else os.path.abspath(os.environ['SPHINX_TEST_TEMPDIR'])
+
 rootdir = path(os.path.dirname(__file__) or '.').abspath()
 tempdir = path(os.environ['SPHINX_TEST_TEMPDIR']).abspath()

+# code from run.py
+print('Temporary files will be placed in %s.' % tempdir)
+if tempdir.exists():
+    tempdir.rmtree()
+tempdir.makedirs()
+
```

Then you write unit tests in the same way as you see in Sphinx unit tests.

Comment: I initially tried to extract `sphinx/tests` and use it, but it wasn't very cooperative (I didn't manage to untangle it in the time available).  I'll take a look at `sphinx-testing`.